# Writing to a file with no quotes, no commas in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have the following code for writing my outputs to a file using Python.

```
ID= # type is <class 'str'>
dictionary={} #Dictionary

    for item in dictionary.keys():
        output=str([Question_ID,item,dictionary[item]])
        target = open('result.relevancy', 'a')
        target.write(output+'\n')
```

The output file is created as follows:

```
['Q1', 'R6', 0.08]
```

And I want to have only the plain text characters as an output as below:

```
Q1    R6   0.08
```

(With no quotes, commas brackets)

Comment: Why are you opening the file inside the loop? Don't do that. Open the file outside the loop, and close it when you've finished writing to it. Even better: open the file using the `with open(` syntax and it will get closed automatically when you leave the `with` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using python3 which I assume you are from the question tags. I would suggest using the print command with the file argument

```
ID= # type is <class 'str'>
dictionary={} #Dictionary

for item in dictionary.keys():
    print(Question_ID,item,dictionary[item],sep=' ',file=open('result.relevancy', 'a'))
```

Although in a loop I think it would be wasting resources to open the file with every iteration so I would also suggest using a file context as follows.

```
ID= # type is <class 'str'>
dictionary={} #Dictionary

with open('result.relevancy', 'a') as fileOut:
    for item in dictionary.keys():
        print(Question_ID,item,dictionary[item],sep=' ',file=fileOut)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily format a string in any format you want:

```
output="%s %s %s" % (Question_ID, item, dictionary[item])
```

You can find more info in https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Also, @zipa answer is valid if you have a variable number of elements

Answer (score 2):

You are turning list into string. What you should do is:

```
output = ' '.join([str(i) for i in [Question_ID, item, dictionary[item]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
ID= # type is <class 'str'>
dictionary={} #Dictionary

    for item in dictionary.keys():
        output=str([Question_ID,item,dictionary[item]])
        target = open('result.relevancy', 'a')
        target.write(output.replace("'", "") +'\n')
```

Comment: then add more replace statements to replace the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format`, i.e.:

```
output = "{} {} {}".format(Question_ID,item,dictionary[item]])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This Code: Simplified

```
import csv
dict={'a':'Q1', "b":'R6', "c":0.08}
data = dict.values()
data
with open('records.csv', 'w') as tsvfile: // can save file in any format CSV or TSV
    writer = csv.writer(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(data)
```